# absolute path is set relatively when using compilerOptions

Tags: typescript

my files look kind of like this:

```
apps
|    something
|         something
|             something
|                 file1.tx
core
|    schema
|        auth.ts
index.ts
tsconfig.json
```

I want to import the stuff from inside `core` without having to `../../../../`.
I tried adding the following inside `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@core/*": ["./core/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["apps/", "index.ts", "core/lib"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "apps/**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

This worked fine when importing from `index.ts` but not from `file1.tsx`

```js
import { something } from '@core/lib/auth'
```

```
Cannot find module '@core/schema/auth' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Im guessing '@core' becomes `./core` making the import search the current directory.
So I would still have to `../../../../@core`.
is there a way to import `root/core` without having to `../../../../` every time?

Comment: What do you have that's doing the actual path mapping? TS config alone won't help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what do I need to share to understand what is doing the path mapping?

Comment: That should work, can you provide a stackblitz or something with a fully working minimal example?

Comment: @MikeJerred I will trying to make a minimal stackblitz and share it. If it's supposed to work it's probably an issue with my settings?

Comment: @MikeJerred i made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nkuuzh?file=tsconfig.json) but I think I found the answer, so I'll share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the `tsconfig.json` but not with  the part I had edited.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@core/*": ["./core/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/", "index.ts", "utils/lib"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

The issue was that I had been making multiple structure changes, and the "include" and "exclude" needed to be fixed, or there would be issues reading the tsconfig.json file.

```
  "include": ["apps/", "index.ts", "core/lib"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "apps/**/*.test.ts"]
```

this made the previous changes on the `path` work without issues.
It was just a bit hard to notice since the tsconfig gave no errors but the imports were failing anyways.